# How to create EditText & Button so that EditText should take new input whenever button is pressed storing prev value?

Tags: java, android, xml

What i did exactly is that user provides input in the EditText and it gets stored in the arrray and later when the button is pressed it clears the field
and now i incremented "number" but when i click button it always takes the previous value of "number". How can i send my incremented value of "number" in OnCreate?
so that whenever i click the button it should take incremented value of "number".
Thanks in Advance!

I tried using for loop it goes endlessly i.e it crashes.pls, help.

public class thirdactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_thirdactivity);

    Intent intent1 = getIntent();

    final int no = intent1.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER4, 0);

    Button Next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validate(no);

        }
    });
}

    public void validate(int number){
    /**
    *created an Array to store the value 
    */
    int DLPoints[] = new int[number];


    /**
    *taking inptut from user and store in userDLPV
    */
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.points);
    int userDLPV = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
    DLPoints[number] = userDLPV;
    editText1.setText("");
    number++
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class thirdactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Integer> userInput = new ArrayList();          

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_thirdactivity);

        Intent intent1 = getIntent();

        int no = intent1.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER4, 0) + 1;

        Button Next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validate(no);

            }
        });
    }

    public void validate(int number){

        /**
         *taking input from user and store in userDLPV
         */
        EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.points);
        editText1.setText("" + number);

        userInput.add(number);

    }
}
```

Comment: This wont store the user input in Array or else where!!

Comment: what about now?